# Wrong SYSDATETIME() from SQL Server Linux Container

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, date, containers

I am having problems with system dates coming from queries on sql server. There is a one hour difference between the actual date and the date of the query. Usually at this time of year my country is in daylight saving time, which advances the clock by one hour, but this has not occurred this year. Is there a way to fix this?

Date inside the sql server container
[image]

Date inside the host
[image]

Comment: What does `GETUTCDATE()` return?

Comment: The times are the same (18:13), using different offsets. Did you forget to apply the latest SQL Server CU perhaps? Which version are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016 and later uses *Windows* timezone names, which is rather ... unfortunate. To get that to work, it has to emulate Windows tz names on Linux through a registry shim. You can check what info is currently used by querying the `sys.time_zone_info` table. Updating the timezone info is done by installing an update. I suspect that's what's causing the problem here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the container was created using the latest sql server 2017 image provided by microsoft and it was not updated after this.

Comment: @Dai it returns the correct UTC time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll give it a try!

Comment: @Vinícius `it was not updated after this.`, well ....If you don't patch your Linux server after a DST rule change, it will also return the wrong offset. `latest sql server 2017 image` doesn't mean it's updated to the latest CU, besides the latest version is 2019.

Comment: @Vinícius *which* tag did you use? If you check [the docker image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) you'll see it has separate images for different versions and CUs. `2017-latest` should correspond to `2017-CU18-ubuntu-16.04`

Comment: I am sorry but did Brazil recently decided not to use DST in 2020 and onwards?

Comment: @SalmanA a [Windows update for Brazil and Morocco DST changes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4507704/dst-changes-in-windows-for-brazil-and-morocco) was released in November 2018.